# How to make Phillips SAA713x TV tuner card work?

Tags: 10.10, multimedia, tv-tuner

I'm new to Ubuntu and have installed Ubuntu 10.10. I have a Phillips SAA713x PCI TV tuner card. Please help me to get it to work in Ubuntu. I dont know any Linux commands.

The output of `lspci` is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Xpress 200 Host Bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 PCI Bridge
00:11.0 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)
0    0:12.0 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 SMBus Controller (rev 82)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 IDE Controller (rev 80)
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200]
02:02.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
02:03.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7130 Video Broadcast Decoder (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

run thses commands :)

```
sudo modprobe -vr saa7134_dvb
sudo modprobe -vr saa7134_alsa
sudo modprobe -vr saa7134
sudo modprobe -v saa7134 card=21
```

Comment: I suggest you to explain what these commands are suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete guide to get SAA7130 TV tuner card to work:

http://sites.google.com/site/jobinau2/saa7130basedtvtunercardunderlinux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.